# How to add listview with variable sized header in android

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am starting with an android project. My requirement is to populate data from database into a list view. For that, I have an xml file that shows the list view, and another xml file which shows how the data is organized in listview.

I wish to have the list view like this. 
http://postimg.org/image/bcrwpue37/

For this, in my xml file that show how data is arranged, I set the layout of the file as Relative layout, and added a table view with one table row, to show data. The length of the data that comes from the db will be of variable size.

My question is, how will I show a header for the listview that arranges the header depending on the width of the column in the table row.

NB:-
I am now here : - I created the table view with a table row that populates data, and in the xml file that contains the listview, I have added a textview just above the listview, but, as the data in the listview may be of diffent length, the listview content doesnot math the header edittext.

Comment: make a linear layout and specify with weight and add table layout below it.. hope it would helps you

Comment: Giridharan , Should I specify width for the linear layout, or for the table?

Comment: make width as 0dp and try to use weight

Comment: That would work for setting the contents of the listview, but how do we have the listview header like that?

Comment: Simply build the table normally with the header row as the first row, inside of a vertical orientation LinearLayout. Next, programmatically remove the first row then add it as the first child to the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

you have rwo solutions:
 1. Use three static TextViews Horizontally Just above the listView in Xml.. for Headings
 2. Use Custom rows for ListView..create xml layout for Heading Row..and for the first time in ListView add the headingRow Layout..

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, particularly the second solution.

Comment: you have to use custom rows for the list view..
1. As you have two type of rows needed here..One for Heading and Second for datas.so you have to create two layouts for two Rows(Heading and Data)
2. In adapter for ListView, you first use the HeadingLayout for row..and then for every record you will use the DataLayout..

Comment: for this you have to learn how to use custom rows to ListView..:)